# Android Things with bindservice and kotlin - onResume and onPause Or Coroutines Or RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, raspberry-pi3, android-things, bindservice

In this project: https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive5, file: ***ModoComFirebase.kt*** I have issue BCM18 is already in use by PID, Because this gpio was opened in ***DriverService.kt*** file before.

My question is: The Application class ***ModoAutomatico.kt*** has no methods onPause and onResume. How to use foreground service in this case to solve my Issue ?[image]

Answer (score 2):

> The Application class ModoAutomatico.kt has no methods onPause and onResume.

This is because the Application class is a singleton. It starts once your app is launched and is never paused, stopped, or destroyed. Since you've bound `DriverService` from the application, this means your service is also always running in the background (unless it were to crash).

> BCM18 is already in use by PID, Because this gpio was opened in DriverService.kt file before.

You can only have one active connection to a peripheral resource at a time. If you want to use a GPIO that is already open in another component, you have to `close()` the active GPIO connection first before you can open a new one.

If you're going to manage all your button connections from within a service, then the rest of the app should be talking to that service to interact with those peripherals instead of trying to juggle multiple GPIO connections.

Comment: This looks good @Devunwired, but i can't put two activies in my manifest.xml (in android things project, only). I've been trying for 5 hours. Already tried: <uses-permission android: name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />. I have tried several and several combinations of intent-filters.